# How can I stop Azure's CDN from caching specific pages?

Tags: azure, caching, cdn

The Azure CDN caches some files for me by default, but I dont want them to be cached.
The files I want to not be cached are `index.html` and `filemanager.php`.

Does anyone know how can I force those specific files to not be cached? Thanks!

Comment: Try to add the Cache-Control header on those files with value: `public, no-cache`.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this I am also struggling with index.html being cached